# Display multiple overlapping points for a route using pylab

Tags: matplotlib

I have a problem of displaying overlapping points in my routing algorithm using the plot(x,y). Specifically i'm looking to plot a route let's say (0,1,2,0,1) and 0 has some coordinates x and y. So if i use plot(x,y) for the above route, route 0-1 will overlap with latter route 0-1
since both of them have same x and y coordinates. How can i show separately so that i can distinguish the two lines using plot(x,y) and pylab.

Comment: you should add some code and if possible some example data, so that others can work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something simple like this?

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

xseries=[0,2,2,3,4 ]   #x values first route
yseries=[0,6,2,8,4 ]   #y values first route

plt.scatter(xseries,yseries)
plt.plot(xseries,yseries,linestyle='--', marker='o')

xseries1=[0,2,6,7  ]  #x values second route
yseries1=[0,2,3,5  ]  #y values second route
plt.plot(xseries1,yseries1)
plt.scatter(xseries1,yseries1)

plt.show()
```